# About type of decltype in object-orient in c++

Tags: c++, oop, decltype

I have a example in c++ about oop and `decltype`:

```
class parent {

};

class child : public parent {

};

int main()
{
    parent * p = new child;
    decltype(*p) c = *p;
}
```

In above code, type of `c` is `parent &` but I want type of `c` is `child`.

Can I do it?

THANK YOU FOR YOUR READING.

Comment: You can either declare `c` as `child` directly, or  declare `p` as `child *`...

Comment: You cannot let the compile-time type of `p` be dependent on a run-time property. Depending on the problem you're attempting to solve this way, there may or may not be a workaround that would work for you. If you're interested in getting help with another approach, please provide some more details about the reason for this.

Comment: You're looking for `typeid`.

Comment: I see. May be it's impossible .Thank you very much!

Comment: Querying the dynamic type of an object to e.g. call a method that is not part of the static type's interface is often a sign of design issues. Maybe if you open another question and describe why you want to do this somebody can suggest a better alternativ design?

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be asking for is not possible.  decltype(expression) will determine the type of value that  evaluates to, while your program is still compiling.  In your example:

```
parent * p = new child;
```

p is declared as a pointer to parent.  So if you dereference the pointer, the type is parent.  It is impossible to know the dynamic type of the pointer through decltype.  Consider:

```
void f(parent * ptr) {
    using type = decltype(*ptr);
    // now what?  type can ONLY be parent
}

class Child1 : public parent { };
class Child2 : public parent { };
void g() {
  Child1 c1;
  Child2 c2;
  f(&c1);
  f(&c2);
}
```

What can function f() do?  It is called with two different types, but the function is written only once.  How would you want this handled, if decltype(*ptr) could yield the most derived type?

Depending on what you want to actually *do* with that type, you might be able to use a virtual function.  For example, if you want to create another object of the derived type, you might create a "clone" factory function, or a getFactory() which can create new instances of whatever type provided the factory.

But you have to have a clearer idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your explanation!